# facebook ads api - can't add custom tracking specs in an ad

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using [facebook-python-ads-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk),and i have followed the official site:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/tracking-specs#examples

with:

**Pixel Tracking
    You can track the performance of different pixels in an ad by specifying the tracking pixel in the ad's tracking_specs field. Let's say that you define:**

```
tracking_specs="[
  {'action.type':'offsite_conversion','fb_pixel':1},
  {'action.type':'offsite_conversion','fb_pixel':2},
  {'action.type':'offsite_conversion','fb_pixel':3}
]"
```

The problem is when I added it to an ad,it shows me the error as

```
"error": {
        "code": 100, 
        "is_transient": false, 
        "error_subcode": 1634019, 
        "error_user_msg": "Please check that a valid and non-empty object id is passed in.", 
        "error_user_title": "The id of the object (post, page, etc) passed in is invalid.", 
        "message": "Invalid parameter", 
        "type": "FacebookApiException", 
        "fbtrace_id": "HhCZrs9+8GH"
      }
```

my code:

```
ad = Ad(parent_id=account_id)
ad[Ad.Field.name] = ad_name
ad[Ad.Field.adset_id] = adset_id
ad[Ad.Field.tracking_specs] = {'action.type': 'offsite_conversion', 'fb_pixel': 6029740175958}
```

when i removed the tracking_specs,it works fine.And i have added the pixel to adset,it also works fine to me.

```
ad_set[AdSet.Field.promoted_object] = {'pixel_id': 6015522072958}
```

So the pixel id is correct.

What am I doing wrong?Thanks for any answer.

Comment: it's an array of specs, have you tried:
`ad[Ad.Field.tracking_specs] = [{'action.type': 'offsite_conversion', 'fb_pixel': 6029740175958}]`

Comment: @PaulBain I've tried it,but i got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn it, i made a GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/2.5/{Ad_ID},
i have added tracking specs to the Ad before.

And then,i got:

```
"tracking_specs": [
    {
      "action.type": [
        "offsite_conversion"
      ],
      "offsite_pixel": [
        "6015521805358",
        "6015522072958",
        "6029740098558",
        "6029740175958"
      ]
    },
    {
      "action.type": [
        "post_engagement"
      ],
      "page": [
        "380039845369159"
      ],
      "post": [
        "1062663363773467"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Did you notice the difference?

It is the **offsite_pixel** field.
In the above example,it was **fb_pixel**. ¯\(°_°)/¯